# JPA : mapping complexe data

Tags: data-binding, jpa

I have this model complex data :

```
@Entity
public class A {
    @id
    public Long id;

    @Column
    public String code;

    @OneToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "A_REF",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_A"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ID_REF"))
    public Set<AbstractRef> refs;

}


@Entity
@Table("T_REF")
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type")
public abstract class AbstractRef {
    @id
    public Long id;

    @Column
    public String value;
}



@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="B")
public class B extends AbstractRef {
}



@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="C")
public class C extends AbstractRef{
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value="D")
public class D extends AbstractRef {
}
```

Example of data base :

```
T_A
ID | NAME
1  |  X
2  |  Y

T_REF
ID | VALUE | TYPE | ID_A
1  |  H    |   B  |  1
2  |  I    |   B  |  1
3  |  H    |   B  |  2
4  |  P    |   C  |  1
5  |  O    |   C  |  1
6  |  O    |   C  |  2
7  |  Z    |   D  |  1
8  |  F    |   D  |  1
9  |  M    |   D  |  2
```

I want to get A(1, X) by using an collection values of B, C and D, not by technical id

```
List<String> values = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"H","I","P","O","Z","F"});
A aWithFunctinnalId = service.getA(values);
```

for my case, collection of values ("H","I","P","O","Z","F") is my functionnal id.

how i can do that ?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use JPQL for this, something like (where :size is the size of the array)

```
Select a from A a where (Select count(r) from a.refs r where r.value in :values) >=:size
```

Comment: Thank you for our reply, but, if i have two instance of "A" with the same size of "REF" not same values, is it still work ?

Comment: i think if in have two instance of "A" with the same size of "REF", i get a wrong result